# Strapi v4 admin panel customization changes are not getting reflected in build

Tags: build, node-modules, strapi, patch-package

I am working on strapi v4 and I want to update the homepage and comment everything on admin panel homepage. I tried updating nodemodules/@strapi/admin pages and created a new build but its not reflecting changes. It used to work in v3 like this. I also tried patch-package approach but still changes were not reflecting, build is completely ignoring the changes.

I also deleted .cache, build, nodemodules/@strapi admin folder, and even disabled internet, but it is still able to create build with original code, even when the admin panel code does not exists anywhere in project directory. I am unable to understand where is it picking the admin panel UI code from, to create the build. And how to make minor changes in admin panel homepage. Please help.